# how to point to my rails application to my domain name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'am using Phusion-passenger and nginx to deploy my rails application, when i goto my server IP-Address i am able to access my rails application, but i cant access it when i go to the domain name. my configuration file looks like this;

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name my_domain.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /home/user/rails_app/public;
    }
```

i have tried configuring my nginx.conf in so many ways but it wasn't accessing the domain name. i also created a symbolic link to my application root folder like this

```
    ln -s /opt/nginx/conf/sites-available/rails_app /opt/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/rails_app
```

i also tried doing this

```
    ln -s /home/user/rails_app/public /home/user/rails_app
```

i updated my nginx.conf file to look like this also

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name my_domain.com www.my_domain.com;
    root /home/user/rails_app/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_base_uri /rails_app;
    rails_env production;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the nginx config file for this app to the domain name, I guess it will help you in the future.
For the domain redirect, you need a DNS server (like Bind). If you're using a VPS server (like Linode, Webbynode or correlated), they provide you a structure to do that without installing a DNS server, it's very simple.
Besides that, your configuration is ok.
If you need some tunning, check [this](https://gist.github.com/rodrigodealer/877495) out.

Comment: i am using Digital Ocean VPS and just like you mention i was able to add my_domain.com via the DNS setting of my server, after which i restarted nginx and it works perfectly ok now.